# Join 2 data frames and add date of execution for each row

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, merge

I want to have a dynamic data frame which is to be updated daily based on a configuration table.

I am starting with the following **static** data frame which is the configuration table.

[image: the configuration table]

I am able to pull results from these SQL Queries in a separate data frame like below.

```
for row in df.itertuples(): 
            df_temp = pd.read_sql(row.SQL_Query, engine)
            df_result = df_result.append(df_temp)
```

[image: Initial Pandas Result]

But I'd like to be able to turn it into this.

[image: the final expected result set]

Comment: append your df_temp (rowcount, failed count) to your df (excel input file) rather than to a new dataframe df_result.

Comment: The purpose is to keep the configuration file static. That's why if you look at look at the final results table, it has the same Table_Name, Column_Name for different dates

Comment: I got it. Then when you read df, add the rows to df_result before you add contents of  df_temp.  Please show us your entire code rather than portions of it.

Comment: That is the entire code. The only thing that happened was execution of SQL queries and the result stored in df_result. Adding rows to df_result will not work since this will be run daily and as a result df_result will be updated daily with the queries executed that day and the results from them

Comment: Where is df and df_result initialized? how is pd imported? you are not showing the ENTIRE code. pls do not assume we know everything.